# Extending a class with a namespace is saying class not found

Tags: php

I have a structure like so:

```
index.php
core
  Exceptions
    ExceptionCore.php
    ExceptionUtil.php
Vendor
  autoload stuff
```

Index file:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

new \core\Exceptions\ExceptionCore\ExceptionCore();
```

ExceptionCore:

```
<?php

Namespace core\Exceptions\ExceptionCore;

Class ExceptionCore
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'fffhf';
    }
}
```

But I am getting the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class
>   'core\Exceptions\ExceptionCore\ExceptionCore' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\user\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\user\index.php on line 5

Comment: Is the ExceptionCore file saved in the right location?

Comment: To my knowledge http://i.imgur.com/A7sPG6R.png

Comment: The file needs to be in `user/core/Exceptions/ExceptionCore`

Comment: Is there any way to change it so the file can be inside Exceptions.

Comment: Because I've changed the namespace to: Namespace core\Exceptions; and the iniate to: new core\Exceptions\ExceptionCore(); and it's still not found

Comment: Edit, had to change autoloader, it was looking inside the exceptions folder. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The autoloader expects to find the class `core\Exceptions\ExceptionCore\ExceptionCore` in file `core/Exceptions/ExceptionCore/ExceptionCore.php`.

Read more about the [`PSR-0`](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) and [`PRS-4`](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) standards.

Comment: How can I do it so it finds the correct file in my current structure... I can rename namespace if needed.

Comment: Remove `ExceptionCore` from the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

index file

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

new core\Exceptions\ExceptionCore\ExceptionCore(); // / delete
```

ExceptionCore:

```
Namespace core\Exceptions\ExceptionCore;

Class ExceptionCore
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'fffhf';
    }
}
```

[image: code is work]

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'core\Exceptions\ExceptionCore\ExceptionCore' not found